# What are the implications of removing define('VERSION', '7.34'); from database.inc

Tags: bootstrapping

I do not want to advertise what version of Drupal I am running. I want to remove the line:

`define('VERSION', '7.34');`

What are the downsides to doing this other than the site not knowing it's own version of Drupal and messing up updates etc...

Note: I am also removing other txt files from the site root that show the version as well. I also know that there is no way to 100% hide this. I just want to know what the implications are for removing the item above.

Edit: I appreciate everyone's input on this issue. I totally agree that security through obscurity doesn't work. However, we all have had that client that thinks they no better than us and requests stuff like this. It's unfortunately the client's site and I have tried educating him. That being said, if he wants to drive his car 100,000 Km without doing an oilchange than that's his choice and he can live with the consequences. So, I just need to know if manually changing this is going to mess me over as the developer or is it something I can do just to make the client happy and move on?

Comment: As well as updates not working you'll get a bunch of warnings in the log for an undefined constant (`VERSION` is used quite a lot in core, a quick grep will show you exactly where). I would question the point though - aside from the meta generator tag, which can be removed separately, I don't think `VERSION` is ever presented to the front end. It'll be in the backend of course (status reports etc), but it doesn't sound like you're trying to hide this from admins

Comment: There is always a way to determine you are using Drupal. misc/states.js, etc files are required ones that you can't block while keeping the functionality intact. Checking the css/JS file contents is enough to detect the minor version (7.34 has some changes in the misc/autocomplete.js, 7.36 has some changes in a different file, etc).

Comment: @Clive, what about manually changing define('VERSION', '7.34'); to something like define('VERSION', '7.00');? (The number being arbitrary)

Comment: i think core would be ok with that but you'd need to check all installed contrib/custom modules to make sure there's nothing relying on it being the correct version

Answer (score 1):

Other than to people that have access to the admin interface, Drupal doesn't advertise sub-version numbers.

The only front-facing way to determine the drupal version information is from the "X-Generator" header which is returned by the server with every request. For drupal version 7, the text returned is "Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)"
This header can be easily removed by adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
Header unset X-Generator
```

If you're looking to keep your sub-version information a secret, be sure all the readme and non essential .txt files in your root **and in your modules folders** are hidden.

Removing the version definition as you stated can cause problems across core and many modules. Not recommended.

[This](https://www.drupal.org/node/766404) is also a good read. TL;DR- don't even worry about your version information not being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

it will be fine if you remove the txt files, also it's a good security practice; However removing the version constant will cause a lot of problems, it used it many places, removing it might lead to big issues.

Comment: Other than updates not working removing the constant shouldn't cause any noticeable problems really. Warnings in the log is about it, I don't think anything will break as such

Comment: @sam2de - Would you be able to cite your statement it's a good security practice? There was a long debate somewhere about removing these files, but its bottom line was that there are no real-life advantages of removing them.

Comment: @AyeshK for example the CHANGELOG.txt is stating what version is used, so you are giving an easy way to some hacker to parse the file and attack if there is any security holes in that specific version. This especially goes who don't keep drupal not up to date all the time.

Comment: Yes, but so are the Last-modified header and other hints a hacker can get just by trying a few. The CHANGELOG is the easiest way, but I think one should focus more on tightening the security instead of hiding that we are using old software.

Comment: Security through obscurity is doomed to failure